# Chicken-Egg Problem when I deploy a Crowdsale with Standard Token

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I just try to implement a [standard token](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol) with a basic [crowdsale](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol) from open zeppelin.

I have everything up and running but the transaction always reverts and I tracked it down to [this line](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol#L127):

```
token.transfer(_beneficiary, _tokenAmount);
```

So within the token contract I get `msg.sender` to be the Crowdsale contract. However, since the crowdsale contract get's deployed ***after*** the token contract, all the tokens are at the address that created the token contract and my guess is that this is causing the revert - because the crowdsale does not have any tokens.

Hence, I have 3 questions:

- is this correct?
- does this simply mean that I need to transfer all tokens to the crowdsale contract?
- is there a way to automate this?

Comment: It is correct, that is the problem and I need to transfer all the tokens to the crowdsale contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to assign all tokens to the creator of the Token and after deployment of the crowdsale the creator will transfer all tokens to the crowdsale

```
// Create 1000 token assigned to 0xOwnerAddress
tokenAddress = deploy_token(1000, { from: "0xOwnerAddress" })

// Deploy crowdsale
crowdsaleAddress = deploy_crowdsale(tokenAddress, { from: "0xOwnerAddress" })

// Transfer tokens to crowdsale
token.transfer(crowdsaleAddress, 1000, { from: "0xOwnerAddress" })
```

Comment: Yup. I managed to do so in the testuite.